# How to programmatically check/uncheck Excel checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, excel

I created a program using VB.NET 2010 that creates Excel documents with checkboxes.

The problem is I cannot check/uncheck the checkboxes by using the code below:

```
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

xlWorkSheet.Shapes("chkDB").ControlFormat.Value = 1 ' doesn't work

xlWorkSheet.OLEObjects("chkDB").Object.Value = 1  ' doesn't work also
```

How do I programmatically check a box in Excel?

Comment: If they're check boxes, wouldn't they use "True" and "False" values as booleans?

Comment: doesn't work also. I don't know if I'm using the correct properties, anyone?

Comment: What's the error you're getting exactly? I think this may be a different issue.